# How to call a function on 'keydown' when an event is passed as a parameter in that function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
$(function (){
    $("#fullName").keydown(handleName);

});

 function handleName(e){
    if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
    } else {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
 }
```

In this I have passed `handleName` on `keydown` but it's not working

Comment: Passing the event to the function is fine. The problem is the `key == N` OR conditions in the  `if` statement are all contradicting each other. What exactly are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: Are you sure it's not calling the function? Put some `console.log`s into your code to see what code is actually running. Or, use the browser's debugger and set some breakpoints.

Comment: it gives an error saying "e is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

event.keyCode has been deprecated. You should use `e.which` instead.

> The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input. For more detail, read about event.charCode on the MDN.

https://api.jquery.com/event.which/

> KeyboardEvent.keyCode: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

And:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

---

Some notes about your code:

It's best to define an anonymous function any time you're setting a listener. This will allow you to send in any variables you'd like as arguments to the function.

```
$(function (){
    var testString = "this is an example of another variable";
    $("#fullName").keydown(function(e) {
        handleName(e, testString); //you can send in more than just the default event argument this way
    });
});
```

Also, if your elements are created dynamically, you'd have to set the listener again on those. It's best to target some parent/ancestor of the element you want to listen to instead:

```
$(function (){
    var testString = "this is an example of another variable";

    //use .on() to set a listener on an ancestor node:
    $(document).on("keydown", "#fullName", function(e) {
        handleName(e, testString); //you can send in more than just the default event argument this way
    });
});
```

And, as I stated in my comment, use `console.log` in different places in the code to see what's being called, and with what arguments. Put this line as the first line in the function `handleName()`:

`console.log("handleName()", e, e.which);`

Comment: So basically, if I want to pass arguments , I have to make an anonymous function and inside I should call the particular function?

Comment: Yes, essentially, get into the habit of writing your listeners that way