# Call a function on Keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

On document ready, this function `performNext` calls fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  performNext();
});
```

`performNext` function hides a current fieldset and shows a next one, my question here is an extension of another question with minimal reproducible example I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76906592/show-next-fieldset-by-next-button)

But it doesn't get called on `keydown`:

```js
$(document).on("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "F1") {
    e.preventDefault();
    performNext();
    console.log("F1");
  };
});
```

performNext function:

```
function performNext() {
    console.log("performNext started");

    var current_fs, next_fs; //fieldsets
    var opacity;
    var current = 1;
    var steps = $("fieldset").length;

    $(".next").click(function() {

        $current_fs = $(this).closest("fieldset");
        $next_fs = $current_fs.next();

        //show the next fieldset
        $next_fs.show();
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        $current_fs.animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            step: function(now) {
                // for making fielset appear animation
                opacity = 1 - now;

                $current_fs.css({
                    'display': 'none',
                    'position': 'relative'
                });
                $next_fs.css({
                    'opacity': opacity
                });
            },
            duration: 500
        });
    });

    $("#msform").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    })
    
    console.log("performNext ended");

}
```

Tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62557385/how-to-call-a-function-on-keydown-when-an-event-is-passed-as-a-parameter-in-th) but not working.

```
console.log("performNext started"); 
console.log("performNext ended"); 
console.log("F1");
```

Are all logged in console, so mapping the F-key works. What am I missing?

Comment: "F1" is logged but performNext() is not executed ? Can you please show the code for performNext() function ?

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946015/call-a-function-on-keydown#comment135645421_76946015) If `F1` is logged by the code shown above, `performNext` was definitely called (and then it returned). So if that's the case, the function is being called but you're not seeing it do what you expect. We can't help you with that from just what's in the question above.  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: yes F1 is logged, but performNext() is not executing. performNext() function can be seen here https://codeshare.io/dw0zoz

Comment: @JessicaKimble Can you add a console.log() at the start of performNext() to check whether it is executing ?

Comment: Never assign click handlers inside functions you plan to reuse. Your `performNext` function creates a click event on top of an existing one. If you want to trigger a click event do so: `$(".next").trigger("click")` - also use the `.on()` method instead of `.click()` otherwise divide your logic into a regular function you can recall, and use it both as standalone or on button click.

Comment: @Emilien Added `console.log("performNext started");` at function start and `console.log("performNext ended");` at function end, they both were logged with F1

Comment: Could you update your code above to provide more context? What does the `performNext` function do? What is its purpose? You will need to add a minimal example that demonstrates the behavior you're describing.

Comment: performNext function hides the current fieldset and shows the next one, this question here is an extension of another question with minimal reproducible example I asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76906592/show-next-fieldset-by-next-button

Comment: @JessicaKimble so the function is executed. Now maybe it doesn't do what it is supposed to do, but that's  another issue. So could you please add the code to your post, let us know what it does and what you want it to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is not good. You're creating click and submit handlers inside a function chat can be potentially called multiple times. The events will add up on top of existing ones. Therefore `$(".next").click(function() {` and `$("#msform").on("submit", function(e) {` should not be part of the `performNext` function. Also your 13 lines of `$current_fs.animate({` can be achieved in only a couple of CSS lines using the CSS `transition` property.  Rather, use an index to navigate your fieldsets and store the desired index in your button's `data-*` attribute:

```js
const $msForm = $("#msform");
const $fieldset = $msForm.find("fieldset");
const stepsTotal = $fieldset.length; // i.e: 4
let stepCurrent = 0; // Start at step index 0

// Instead of "performNext()", use a more flexible goToStep() 
// function that accepts a step index:
function goToStep(index) {
  const $step = $fieldset.eq(index);
  $fieldset.not($step).removeClass("is-active");
  $step.addClass("is-active");
}

// Got to step index (stored in button's data-* attribute)
$("[data-gotostep]").on("click", function() {
  stepCurrent = Number($(this).data("gotostep"));
  goToStep(stepCurrent);
});

// Go to next step
$(document).on("keydown", (evt) => {
  if (evt.originalEvent.key === "F1") {
    evt.preventDefault();
    stepCurrent += 1;
    stepCurrent = Math.min(stepCurrent, stepsTotal - 1); 
    goToStep(stepCurrent);
  };
});

// Init:
goToStep(0); // Show first step

// Other stuff...
$msForm.on("submit", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
});
```

```css
#msform fieldset {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s; /* instead of jQuery .animate() */
}

#msform fieldset.is-active {
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="msform">
  <fieldset>
    <label>1/3 Your name:<br><input name="name" type="text"></label><br>
    <button type="button" data-gotostep="1">Next</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button type="button" data-gotostep="0">Back</button><br>
    <label>2/3 Your surname<br><input name="surname" type="text"></label><br>
    <button type="button" data-gotostep="2">Next</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button type="button" data-gotostep="1">Back</button><br>
    <label>3/3 Your age<br><input name="age" type="number"></label><br>
    <button type="button" data-gotostep="3">Next</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button type="submit" data-gotostep="0">Start all over</button><br>
    <label>You're all set!</label><br>
    <button type="submit">Finish</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to press <kbd>F1</kbd> and focus on the next `<fieldset>`, you could try the following procedure:

- If there is no previous input focus (initial load), find the form's first field and focus on the first input.
- If a field is already receiving focus, find the next one or wrap around (relative to the form).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  performNext();
});

$(document).on('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'F1') {
    e.preventDefault();
    performNext();
  };
});

function performNext() {
  var $focusedInput = $(':focus'), $currFieldset, $nextFieldset;
  if ($focusedInput.length === 0) {
    $nextFieldset = $('form > fieldset').first();
  } else {
    $currFieldset = $focusedInput.closest('fieldset');
    $nextFieldset = $currFieldset.next('fieldset');
    // Wrap around
    if ($nextFieldset.length === 0) {
      var $form = $currFieldset.closest('form');
      $nextFieldset = $form.find('fieldset:first-child'); 
    }
  }
  $nextFieldset.show();
  $nextFieldset.find('input').first().focus();
  // hide the current fieldset with style
  if ($currFieldset != null) {
    $currFieldset.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
      step: function(now) {
        // for making fielset appear animation
        var opacity = 1 - now;
        $currFieldset.css({ display: 'none', position: 'relative' });
        $nextFieldset.css({ opacity: opacity });
      },
      duration: 500
    });
  }
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <fieldset id="name-fs">
    <legend>What is your name? (Step 1/2)</legend>
    <label for="given-name-txt">Given name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="given-name-txt" name="given-name" placeholder="Jane" />
    <label for="surname-txt">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surname-txt" name="surname" placeholder="Doe" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="agree-fs">
    <legend>Do you agree?  (Step 2/2)</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="agree-rad-yes" name="agree" value="true" />
    <label for="agree-rad-yes">I agree</label>
    <input type="radio" id="agree-rad-no" name="agree" value="false" />
    <label for="agree-rad-no">No</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```